# Django Custom User Authentication with Email and IP Address

Tags: django

I want to move one of our application (PHP based) to Django. I couldn't solve how to do following requirement.

I don't want to use username field. I don't even need this field on database, ofcourse I need some extra field on database such as "Job Title" etc. I'm using email field as unique value on login process.

Also application has to check out user ip addresses and each user may have one or more ip address. I used to store user ip addresses in another table called as user_ip. But I don't know how to check out this during authentication process.

Any idea and sample codes ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can inherit django's awesome auth system models. e.g. User model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUser(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User) #<-- Django's User 
   # other extra fields you want 

class User_IP(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
   u_ip = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

login cicle:

```
def my_view(request):
   username = request.POST['username']
   password = request.POST['password']
   user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
   if user is not None:
       if user.is_active:
           customuser = user.get_profile()
           # check for IP etc.. then:
           login(request, user)
           # Redirect to a success page.
       else:
           # Return a 'disabled account' error message
   else:
       # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can use user_ip field as FK to another table which contains ip address of users. How can I use it on during login process ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the documentation for creating a custom authentication backend.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

If I were to take a guess at what this would look like for your situation, it would be something like this...

## models.py

```
class IPAddress(models.Model):
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ip_address = models.ManyToManyField(IPAddress)
```

## authentication_backends.py

```
class EmailIPAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, email=None, ip_address=None):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(user__email=email, ip_address=ip_address).user
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
             return None
```

Then you could plug this authentication backend into settings.py...

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 'path.to.your.custom.authetication_backends.EmailIPAuthBackend')
```

When logging a user in now, Django will first attempt it's default authentication functionality and when that fails it will then try your custom authentication functionality.

If you really have a need to remove usernames from your base User, then you would need to take a look here, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model